# VMWare Windows 98 - Abnormal Termination TestBed: NO DirectDraw hardware

Tags: windows, vmware, windows-98

I have downloaded the Windows 98 Virtual Machine Image from [here](https://winworldpc.com/product/windows-98/98-second-edition).

I installed the game `hogs of war` but after I start the game I get the following messagebox:

[image: Abnormal Termination]

**Abnormal Termination**

**TestBed: NO DirectDraw hardware!!!! (Error Code: 81197)**

And the whole windows UI freezes.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I very much doubt VMware Workstation(?) offers support for 3D acceleration with Windows 98.

Comment: So this means it is impossible to play this old game on a virtual machine? It does only work on a real physical machine?